# MongoDB - Update values in object inside an array with different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

I have many documents in trainer_copy collection (MongoDB) but here I have shown only 2. I need to update many documents.

```
//1

  {
    "jobRoles": [{
            "sector": {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "Electronics & Hardware"
            }
        },
        {
            "sector": {
                "id": "23",
                "name": "Management"
            }
        },
        {
            "sector": {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "Construction"
            }
        },
        {
            "sector": {
                "id": "11",
                "name": "Electronics & Hardware"
            }
        },
    ]
}

//2
{
    "jobRoles": [{
            "sector": {
                "id": "20",
                "name": "Iron & Steel"
            }
        },
        {
            "sector": {
                "id": "20",
                "name": "Iron & Steel"
            }
        },
        {
            "sector": {
                "id": "9",
                "name": "Construction"
            }
        },
    ]
}
}
```

I need the updated result as below:

```
//1
{
    "jobRoles" : [ 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "11",
                "name" : "Electronics and Hardware"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "23",
                "name" : "Management"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "9",
                "name" : "Construction"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "11",
                "name" : "Electronics and Hardware"
            }
        }, 
]
}

//2
{
    "jobRoles" : [ 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "20",
                "name" : "Iron and Steel"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "20",
                "name" : "Iron and Steel"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "9",
                "name" : "Construction"
            }
        }, 
    ]
}
}
```

I tried this method

```
var tc = [
    {"name":"Electronics & Hardware",            "new_name" :  "Electronics and Hardware"},
    {"name":"Furniture & Fittings",              "new_name" :  "Furniture and Fittings"},
    {"name":"Gems & Jewellery",                  "new_name" :  "Gems and Jewellery"},
    {"name":"Instrumentation",                   "new_name" :  "IASC"},
    {"name":"Iron & Steel",                      "new_name" :  "Iron and Steel"},
    ]
    
    
tc.forEach(x => {

db.trainer_copy.updateMany({"jobRoles.sector.name":x["name"]},
{
    $set: {
        "jobRoles.$.sector.name": x["new_name"]
        }
    })
})
```

But I got the result as below

```
//1
{
    "jobRoles" : [ 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "11",
                "name" : "Electronics and Hardware"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "23",
                "name" : "Management"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "9",
                "name" : "Construction"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "11",
                "name" : "Electronics & Hardware"
            }
        }, 
]
}

//2
{
    "jobRoles" : [ 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "20",
                "name" : "Iron and Steel"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "20",
                "name" : "Iron & Steel"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "sector" : {
                "id" : "9",
                "name" : "Construction"
            }
        }, 
    ]
}
}
```

Only the first object in jobRoles is updating the rest remains the same. I cannot use `$[]` positional argument as per my knowledge as it updates all the objects inside the array. I don't want that.

I know another method like each time I have to use if condition to update its value. But for 25 or more conditions its difficult to write each time if condition. If there any method or any different query in javascript or MongoDB it will be very helpful to me. Sorry I couldn't give a better name for the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the answer but I notice in your query you use `jobRoles.sector.name`, but in your update you use `jobRoles.$.sector.name` with the `$`. If this is correct I'll make an answer of it.

Comment: for matching i am using jobRoles.sector.name but for update inside an array if you dont use $ it will throw you an error

Comment: I see. I think you do want `$[]`. `$` alone means only update the first item, `$[]` means all that match, not all (indescriminately).  See here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with-identifier

Comment: I tried "jobRoles.$[ ].sector.name"  but it got updated for all names for construction also it got updated as "Electronics and Hardware" and here https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/#update-nested-arrays-in-conjunction-with-identifier they have shown only inside an array not inside an object which is within that array with different values

Comment: Oh gosh I hope you're not running this on production! If not and you can try something else, I think you want to use the option `arrayFilters` to match instead of the query parameter. See the last example in that link (I'm sorry I didn't look more closely)

Comment: No way...I have made duplicate collection in my local and checking the query there. I don't know much about arrayFilters but still i will give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var tc = [
    {"name":"Electronics & Hardware",            "new_name" :  "Electronics and Hardware"},
    {"name":"Furniture & Fittings",              "new_name" :  "Furniture and Fittings"},
    {"name":"Gems & Jewellery",                  "new_name" :  "Gems and Jewellery"},
    {"name":"Instrumentation",                   "new_name" :  "IASC"},
    {"name":"Iron & Steel",                      "new_name" :  "Iron and Steel"},
    ]
    
    
tc.forEach(x => {

db.trainer_copy.updateMany({"jobRoles.sector.name":x["name"]},
{
    $set: {
        "jobRoles.$[jobRole].sector.name": x["new_name"]
        }
    },
    { arrayFilters: [{ "jobRole.sector.name": x["name"] }] }
    )
})
```

In the above answer, the name jobRole is a placeholder for index in the array that matches the filter { "jobRole.sector.name" : x ["name"] }.

x ["name"] is old name and updating it to new name i.e. x["new_name"].